# how to pass style props of a reusable component in react native using typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to make a reusable component in react-native using typescript.
Most of the time I use this way as a simple react-native project. This time I want to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript. how can I do it?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";

const AppText = ({ children, style } ) => {
    return (
    <Text style={[styles.textcommon, style]} > {children} </Text>

    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textcommon: {
        fontSize: RFValue(18),
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: '#fff',
        fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'Roboto-Light' : 'Avenir',
    }
})

export default AppText;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
const myChildWithPAssedStyle = ({ style, ...props}: {style: React.CSSProperties}) => {
 
}
```

In case you're asking for the `React.CSSProperties` type...